# Find index position in nested lists for match

Tags: r, list, indexing

I want to find the Indexes of the match of a nested list and a target value (11).

**Data:**

```r
f <- list(
  list(1, 2, 3),
  list(4, 5, list(8, list(11, 12)))
)
```

**Desired Output for target value = 11.:**

```
c(2, 3, 2, 1)
```

**Printed:**

```
 f
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 2

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 3


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 4

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 5

[[2]][[3]]
[[2]][[3]][[1]]
[1] 8

[[2]][[3]][[2]]
--->>>  [[2]][[3]][[2]][[1]]  <<<----
-->>>> [1] 11 <<<----

[[2]][[3]][[2]][[2]]
[1] 12
```

**What i tried:**

match with `unlist(data)`, Looking for Parameter in `which()` and Looking into `arrInd()`.

I would avoid running multiple for loops in R. It would be better to do all loops in C, C++,... Before implementing it myself i wanted to check if i am missing a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try `melt()` from `reshape2`:

```
melted_lst <- reshape2::melt(f) 
melted_lst[sort(colnames(melted_lst))][melted_lst$value == 11, ]

  L1 L2 L3 L4 value
7  2  3  2  1    11
```

Or with `melt()` from `data.table` (as mentioned by @IceCreamToucan):

```
melted_lst <- data.table::melt(f)
melted_lst[sort(colnames(melted_lst))][melted_lst$value == 11, ]
```

Comment: `s[,order(names(s))][s$value==11,]`

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = function(x, sep = ".") {
    names(x) = paste0(seq_along(x))
    while(any(sapply(x, class) == "list")) {
        ind = sapply(x, class) == "list"
        temp = unlist(x[ind], recursive = FALSE)
        names(temp) = paste0(rep(names(x)[ind], lengths(x[ind])),
                             sep,
                             sequence(lengths(x[ind])))
        x = c(x[!ind], temp)
    }
    return(x)
}
f2 = foo(f)
names(which(unlist(f2) == 11))
#[1] "2.3.2.1"
```

Comment: great, this solution appeared to be more robust concerning the data structure for certain cases i encountered.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done with `rrapply` in the `rrapply`-package (extended version of base `rapply`). The `condition` argument decides to which elements `f` should be applied, and the `.xpos` argument in the `f` function evaluates to the position of the element in the nested list. `how = "flatten"` discards all list elements that do not satisfy `condition` and returns a flattened list:

```r
library(rrapply)

rrapply(f, condition = function(x) x == 11, f = function(x, .xpos) .xpos, how = "flatten")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another take using `tibble::enframe()` :

```r
library(tidyverse)
f <- list(
  list(1, 2, 3),
  list(4, 5, list(8, list(11, 12)))
)

df <- enframe(f)
while(!all(lengths(df$value)==1)) df <- df %>% 
  mutate(value = map(value,~enframe(.) %>% mutate_at("value", as.list))) %>%
  unnest(value)
df <- df %>% unnest(value)
df
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>    name name1 name2 name3 value
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1     1     1
#> 2     1     2     1     1     2
#> 3     1     3     1     1     3
#> 4     2     1     1     1     4
#> 5     2     2     1     1     5
#> 6     2     3     1     1     8
#> 7     2     3     2     1    11
#> 8     2     3     2     2    12

filter(df, value == 11) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  unlist(use.names = F)
#> [1] 2 3 2 1
```