# Randomly extract elements in a list which belongs to a list and know the postition

Tags: r

I have a list consisting of several lists like this:

```
example_list <- list(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,0,0,0,1),matrix(1:12,3,4),matrix(1:12,4,3))
```

How can I randomly extract just one element from example_list, and know exactly the position of the element? For example if I picked 1, how could I know this 1 is the first element of the second list and not any others? The return should be the order of the sublist and also the order of the element in the sublist.

Note that, all sublists are formed of numeric, not string or character.

I have searched but still failed to find a suitable solution, can someone help me out? Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @akrun reminding me melt() function. Here is the solution to my question:

```
example_list <- list(matrix(c(1,2,3,4)),matrix(c(1,0,0,0,1)),matrix(1:12,3,4),matrix(1:12,4,3))
# To avoid getting NA, I transform arrays in list to matrix, so that I can get the index of rows and columns.
get_res <- function(example_list){
output <- melt(setNames(example_list,seq_along(rates)))
res <- output[sample(dim(output)[1], 1),] # sample(dim(output)[1], 1) This confirms I get only one number
if (as.integer(res$L1) <= 2){
ind1 = res$L1
ind2 = res$Var1}
else{ind1 = res$L1
ind2 = c(res$Var1,res$Var2)}
result <- list(ind1 = ind1, ind2 = ind2)
return(result)}
get_res(example_list)
```

in1 tells the sub list the random belongs to, and ind2 tell the order of the random in this sub list.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
set.seed(99)
sample_list <- function(x) {
  i <- sample(length(x), 1)
  list(i, x[[i]])
}

sample_list(example_list)
```

Gives:

```
[[1]]
[1] 4

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10
[3,]    3    7   11
[4,]    4    8   12
```

Comment: Thanks! I am sorry that I might don't make my question clearly. I can only pick one element or I should say value in the list. From my example, that should be just one numeric (1 or 2 or 3, etc.) Your answer just linked the order and the the content of this order together. For example, if the system randomly chose 1, and I get the return with information like this: 2, 5, then I know this 1 is just from the second element of the whole list, and it is the fifth value of its small list.

Answer (score 0):

We may name the `list` with the sequence of `list` and use `sample` on the `melt`ed data

```
library(reshape2)
d1 <- melt(setNames(example_list, seq_along(example_list)))
```

Now do the `sample` and get the corresponding `list` index along with the row/column index

```
> d1[d1$value == sample(d1$value, 1),]
   value Var1 Var2 L1
19    10    1    4  3
31    10    2    3  4
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I think this is a solution to how to extract a list of a list. From the output, I can only get to know the order of the value in the whole list I randomly chose. For example, you showed me you have randomly chosen the fourth element of the list, that's not what I want. I can only chose one value, for example, value 5, and the return will tell me, this is from the fourth list of the big whole list, and it is at the first row, the second column. The result should give me the information like this: 4, [1,2].

Comment: @MD_Yang perhaps the update helps

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57420694/9463489) question might work for your example:

```
library(data.table)

f <- list(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,0,0,0,1),matrix(1:12,3,4),matrix(1:12,4,3))
dt <- data.table::melt(f)
setcolorder(setcolorder(dt, sort(colnames(dt))), "value")
```

Sampling a value from `f` is the same as sampling `dt$value`. If row `i` were sampled, the corresponding value could be retrieved from `f`:

```
i <- sample(nrow(dt), 1)
ifelse(is.na(dt$Var1[i]), f[[dt$L1[i]]], f[[dt$L1[i]]][dt$Var1[i], dt$Var2[i]])
```

However, list structures can get pretty complex. The above solution wouldn't work for the following object, which contains a 3-dimensional list array of matrices nested inside a nested list:

```
set.seed(94)
f <- list(c(1:4), c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1), matrix(1:12, 3, 4), list(matrix(1:12, 4, 3), `dim<-`(lapply(1:18, function(i) matrix(sample(1:10, 4), nrow = 2)), c(3,3,2))))
```

Here's a recursive function that will return a `data.table` with the address for each value in the object. Positive values in the `i` columns indicate list indices (accessed using double brackets), and negative values indicate vector/matrix/array indices (accessed using single brackets). Note that it uses 1-D indexing for matrices and arrays.

```
library(data.table)

faddress <- function(obj) {
  if (is.atomic(obj)) {
    return(data.table(i = -seq_along(obj)))
  } else {
    return(rbindlist(lapply(seq_along(obj), function(i) cbind(i, faddress(obj[[i]]))), fill = TRUE))
  }
}
```

Attach the values to the resulting `data.table` with `cbind`:

```
dt <- cbind(unlist(f), faddress(f))
```

For example, the 94th row of `dt` is:

```
> dt[94]
   V1 i1 i2 i3 i4
1:  1  4  2 16 -1
```

The value of `1` is retrieved using the following:

```
> f[[4]][[2]][[16]][1]
[1] 1
```